# Search in array on two parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I search in a array on two parameters?

I want to search every event based on date`[0]` and name`[1]`

```
if(DATE = MYDATE && Name = "Alle") {
}
```

My array: `calendarevents` :

```
0 ["01102017", "Frida", "til Mie L fødselsdag", "10:30"] (4)
1 ["02102017", "Frida", "skolefoto", "08:15"] (4)
2 ["02102017", "Kevin", "tandlæge ", "09:00"] (4)
3 ["02102017", "Heidi", "angsthold", "10:00"] (4)
4 ["02102017", "Heidi", "mindfullnes ", "12:30"] (4)
5 ["02102017", "Maia", "Gymnastik", "17:30"] (4)
6 ["03102017", "Maia", "salen", "09:15"] (4)
7 ["03102017", "Heidi", "møde bhv ", "10:30"] (4)
8 ["03102017", "Alle", "kan kode", "20:00"] (4)
9 ["04102017", "Alle", "BH Cykeldag", null] (4)
10 ["05102017", "Alle", "Aalborg", null] (4)
11 ["05102017", "Lærke", "omplacering", null] (4)
12 ["05102017", "Heidi", "nada", "09:00"] (4)
13 ["05102017", "Heidi", "kraftcenter ", "13:00"] (4)
14 ["05102017", "Lærke", "gymnastik", "15:45"] (4)
15 ["06102017", "Frida", "hos Ole", null] (4)
16 ["07102017", "Alle", "Ole fødsesldag", null] (4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. For example,

```
var results = calendarevents.filter(function(row) {
  return row[0] === MYDATE && row[1] === 'Alle';
})
```